# Can I say the residuals have an ARCH effect in this plot?

Tags: arch

[image]

If there were no ARCH effects in the residuals, the ACF & PACF should be zero at all lags. However, here in the ACF the first two lags are out of the band; and in the PACF lags 1, 2 and 18 are out of band.

What can I conclude? Can I say volatility clustering or ARCH is present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are ARCH effects in your data, because the ACF and PACF values are statistically significantly different from zero.

- For high lags you could interpret them as being due to chance (because at 95% confidence level, on average 5% of the observed statistics will exceed the confidence bound purely due to chance).
- However, for low lags (such as 1 for ACF and 1, 2 for PACF) the effect can be thought of as being genuine, especially if there is a subject-matter explanation for it. (Don't pay attention to lag 0 in ACF, it indicates variance rather than autocorrelation.)

You could do formal testing for presence of ARCH effects using the ARCH-LM test. But you already know the answer for low lags. Meanwhile, for high lags the power of the ARCH-LM test w.r.t. detecting the low-order ARCH effects will go down, because these effects will be swamped by absence of ARCH effects in the higher-order lags.

You could try an ARCH(2) model to account for the ARCH effects.